# jQuery find() to find the <figcaption> text that follows <a>

Tags: jquery, lightbox, caption

I cannot find the way to find the text of the  and to insert it into the title attribute of the lightbox link. The code below returns the text of the first caption, whatever link I click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[rel^=lightbox]').attr('title', $(this).find('figcaption').html());

        });
</script>

<body>
<a href="images/image-7.jpg" rel="lightbox[9-10-12]"><figure>
        <img src="images/thumbs/image-7_thumb.jpg" alt="First image" >
        <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
<br/>
<a href="images/image-8.jpg" rel="lightbox[9-10-12]"><figure>
        <img src="images/thumbs/image-8_thumb.jpg"/>
        <figcaption>Thing 2</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this:

```
$('a[rel^=lightbox]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', $(this).find('figcaption').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your click event..??

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('a').click(function(){
   $('a[rel^=lightbox]').attr('title', $(this).find('figcaption').html());
   })
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  $('a[rel^=lightbox]').attr('title', $(this).parent().find('figcaption').text();
```

Need to find the `figcaption` element inside the parent of the `a` element.